# x-axis position in scichart

Tags: ios, scichart

Currently I'm new to scichart and I've a very simple question how can I deal with x-axis or y-axis as objects from `UIView`, so I can set their exact position using `NSLayoutConstrant`, not just aligned top, left, right and bottom.
for example I need to position the x-axis about 8 pixels above the containing view bottom

Comment: It's not possible to do that in SciChart.iOS without modifying the source code. The axis positions are only available as left, right, top, bottom.

Answer (score 1):

In [SciChart iOS v3](https://www.scichart.com/ios-chart-features) it is now possible to place axis in the centre of the chart, or specify a custom axis location [using the Axis Layout API](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/ios/current/axis-layout---central-axis.html).

From the [documentation](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/ios/current/axis-layout---central-axis.html):

> SciChart supports axis in the centre of the chart. It requires changes to the layout process in ISCILayoutManager to specify the exact axis position inside a chart area. Please read on to learn how to do such an advanced layout. As an example it’s also demonstrated in the Shifted Axes Example.

[image]